# Dropdown Menu is not overlapping Slick Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, slick.js

I have jQuery Slick Gallery and inside it I have a Dropdown Menu. A button shows the currently selected entry and the menu entries are an unordered list which appear when the button is clicked.

The unordered list is hidden at the bottom edge but should appear above the dots. You can see the problem also on the image below:
[image: Visualization of Problem]

An example what I try to do you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/45cst6nq/

**HTML**

```
<section class="slider">
  <div>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>Please select</li>
      <li>Point 1</li>
      <li>Point 2</li>
      <li>Point 3</li>
      <li>Point 4</li>
      <li>Point 5</li>
      <li>Point 6</li>
      <li>Point 7</li>
      <li>Point 8</li>
      <li>Point 9</li>
      <li>Point 10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>slide2</div>
  <div>slide3</div>
  <div>slide4</div>
  <div>slide5</div>
  <div>slide6</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
$c1: #3a8999;
$c2: #e84a69;

.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
    background: $c1;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
     background: $c2;
}

.list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".slider").slick({
    autoplay: false,
    dots: true,
    responsive: [{ 
        breakpoint: 500,
        settings: {
            dots: false,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: false,
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
        } 
    }]
});
```

This is a simplyfied example to demonstrate the issue. The components I am showing on my customor project are a little bit more complex.

I already tried to fix this with changing z-index and overflows. It looks like it's working when I set overflow-x to visible but than the cloned slides also get visible. Using `overflow-y: visible;` doesn't work.
Why does only `overflow-x: visible` shows the list correctly overlapping, but `overflow-y: visible;` does not? For me this doesn't make sense.

Is there a possibility to solve the issue? I like the slick gallery in general and don't want to write my own for this case.

Comment: This is exactly my problem, have you found solutoin to this?

Comment: Hey anyone find the solution? it is also happening with me i am using silk slider in this slider i have a select menu when i open select menu it doesn't allow to flow outside the slider because slider's top layer have css property overflow: hidden

is there any solution to pop out specific element forcefully from parent overflow: hidden ???

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the class slick.list. I added some colour to your Li elements to show it clearer. Add this and you will see them:

```
.list li {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.slick-list {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/62sdgv5a/

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesn't solve the problem. I get an scrollbar inside the container. But the list has to appear above the dots. With ```overflow-y: visible``` the list is not overlapping the slick container.

Comment: I updated my question with an image. I hope this explains what I want to achieve. :)

Comment: it is overlapping now :) Hope this is what you ment

Comment: Yes, it's overlapping, but now you see the slides to the left and right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve.

An unordered list can't be a dropdown i.e. a html select element. I forked your fiddle and used a select instead of the ul and everything looks ok.

https://jsfiddle.net/o1prjfcw/2/

```
<section class="slider">
    <div>
      <select>
        <option value="point1">Point 1</option>
        <option value="point2">Point 2</option>
        <option value="point3">Point 3</option>
        <option value="point4">Point 4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>slide2</div>
...
```

You can obviously stile your select element to something that fits the rest of your page.

Comment: The dropdown is  build with a button and a unordered list. The button shows the selected entry and the unordered list the option values. This was choosen because option elements can't be styled in the way my customer wants it. I edited my question and I hope it's now clear what I try to achieve.

Comment: Ok so it's clearer now but my point still stands. You can't have an ul element act as a select element.

You can definitely style the dropdown element. Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrfm79f3/)

If you're trying to use the first slide as some sort of navigator i.e. duplicate the functionality of the dots but add titles for the slides I would advise against that. There's a reason why navigation interfaces are usually outside of the things they navigate about :)

Comment: Btw Dropdown is build in a similar way like bootstrap does it. The dropdown does not manupilate the slick itself but shows additional Information on the slide.

Comment: I updated my question with an image. I hope this explains what I want to achieve. :)

Comment: this is not a good solution to show overflow, it will show all other things which don't want to show. Is there any solution to show specific element visible outside the parent when parent have set css property overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not very clear as to what you want to achieve, but if you are trying to fit in the list element into the slider i will suggest you add this code to you css.

```
.slider div .list{
  position: relative;
}
```

This allows the list to show in the slide. This doesn't affect other slide.

Comment: I don't want to fit the Stuff inside the container. I need the list to overflow the bottom border. My customer wants it...so I have to do that.

Comment: I have modified the answer.

Comment: I updated my question with an image. I hope this explains what I want to achieve. :)